# Unknown symbol in module but what symbol?

Tags: drivers, kernel, dependencies, proc

I compile a driver following the documentations. But when I try loading them via

```
insmod onebox_wlan_nongpl.ko
```

, I receive an error message:

> insmod: Error: could not insert module onebox_wlan_nongpl.ko: Unknown symbol in module

I know this is due to wrong order of loading `.ko` files but it does not tell me which module does it depend on. I would like to know what symbol is unknown to file the module that I should load first.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check the missing symbols in dmesg using `dmesg | tail`. If you want to check if the symbols are actually in your symbol table, check using `cat /proc/kallsyms | grep <function_name>`
Similar issue:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1360950

Answer (score 0):

To see which symbols are actually missing, look into the kernel log using `dmesg`.
It will show you the exact symbols.
If you wrote the kernel module yourself and it for example relies on a framework like the device mapping framework, the dependecy has to be loaded first. Here an example I ran into:

I wrote a [device mapper](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/device-mapper/index.html), which depends on the device mapping framework.
On insertion, this happens:

```
$ sudo insmod some-module.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module some-module.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

Inspect the kernel log:

```
$ sudo dmesg
[     XX.XXXXXX] some-module.ko: Unknown symbol dm_per_bio_data (err -2)
[     XX.XXXXXX] some-module.ko: Unknown symbol dm_put_device (err -2)
...
```

Inspect the loaded modules:

```
$ lsmod | grep dm
<NOTHING>
```

Insert the device mapping target driver:

```
$ sudo modprobe dm_mod
$ lsmod | grep dm
dm_mod            184320 0
```

Now insert the original module an the error is resolved.